ionic ion-nav and ion-menu vanilla js
I am trying to make a small app with ionic without using framework, just vanilla js. I'm simply trying to create a menu that allows me to travel through the components managed by an ion-nav... I imagine I'm doing something wrong, but the links in the menu don't allow me to move, they don't work.
<body>
  <ion-app>
    <ion-menu content-id="main-content" menuId="menu">
      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
          <ion-title>Fideliza</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
      <ion-content class="ion-padding">
        <ion-list>

          <ion-item lines="full" menu-close ui-sref="page-clientes">
            <ion-icon aria-hidden="true" name="people" slot="start"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>Clientes</ion-label>
          </ion-item>

          <ion-nav-link router-direction="forward" component="page-mailing">
            <ion-item lines="full">
              <ion-icon aria-hidden="true" name="mail" slot="start"></ion-icon>
              <ion-label>Mailing</ion-label>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-nav-link>


          <ion-item lines="full">
            <ion-icon aria-hidden="true" name="reader" slot="start"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>Plantillas</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item lines="full">
            <ion-icon aria-hidden="true" name="construct" slot="start"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>Configuración</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>

    <ion-nav root="page-clientes" id="main-content"></ion-nav>
  </ion-app>





  <script>
    class Clientes extends HTMLElement {
      connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = `
            <div class="ion-page">
                <ion-header>
                    <ion-toolbar>
                        <ion-buttons slot="start">
                            <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
                        </ion-buttons>
                        <ion-title>Fideliza V1</ion-title>
                    </ion-toolbar>
                </ion-header>
              <ion-content class="ion-padding">
                <h1>Clientes</h1>
                    <ion-item lines="full">
                        <ion-nav-link router-direction="forward" component="page-mailing">
                            <ion-icon aria-hidden="true" name="mail" slot="start"></ion-icon>
                            <ion-label>Mailing</ion-label>
                        </ion-nav-link>
                    </ion-item>
              </ion-content>
            </div>
            `;
      }
    }
    class Mailing extends HTMLElement {
      connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = `
            <div class="ion-page">
              <ion-header>
                <ion-toolbar>
                  <ion-buttons slot="start">
                    <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
                  </ion-buttons>
                  <ion-title>Page Two</ion-title>
                </ion-toolbar>
              </ion-header>
              <ion-content class="ion-padding">
                <h1>Page Two</h1>
                <div>
                  <ion-nav-link router-direction="forward" component="page-three">
                    <ion-button>Go to Page Three</ion-button>
                  </ion-nav-link>
                </div>
              </ion-content>
            </div>
            `;
      }
    }
    class Plantillas extends HTMLElement {
      connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = `
            <div class="ion-page">
              <ion-header>
                <ion-toolbar>
                  <ion-buttons slot="start">
                    <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
                  </ion-buttons>
                  <ion-title>Page Three</ion-title>
                </ion-toolbar>
              </ion-header>
              <ion-content class="ion-padding">
                <h1>Page Three</h1>
              </ion-content>
            </div>
            `;
      }
    }

    customElements.define('page-clientes', Clientes);
    customElements.define('page-mailing', Mailing);
    customElements.define('page-plantillas', Plantillas);
  </script>




</body>

For them I used an ion-nav-link within the menu as seen in the sample code
Basically I want to have a menu that allows me to move in between the elements of the nav-ion.
I've done this for example with onsen and it's much simpler and there's much more documentation, but in ionic if you don't use Angular I don't see too much documentation to use just vanilla
